# How to read a local file in Windows

Tags: python, apache-spark

I want to read a local file into spark. I'm using Windows. Used the following command:

```
input = sc.textFile("D://sample.txt")
```

I tried every possible combination, but constantly get the following or very similar error.

I tried the following:

- adding file:/// and file://
- adding file:\\ and file:\
- D:/sample.txt
- D:\sample.txt
- D:\sample.txt

The current working directory is D:\ and the file exists on D:\

Anyone an idea?

```
>>> input = sc.textFile("D://sample.txt")
15/10/27 02:37:37 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(157288) called with curMem=7
891904, maxMem=556038881
15/10/27 02:37:37 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_46 stored as values in memor
y (estimated size 153.6 KB, free 522.6 MB)
15/10/27 02:37:37 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(14276) called with curMem=80
49192, maxMem=556038881
15/10/27 02:37:37 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_46_piece0 stored as bytes in
 memory (estimated size 13.9 KB, free 522.6 MB)
15/10/27 02:37:37 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_46_piece0 in memory on
localhost:52887 (size: 13.9 KB, free: 529.6 MB)
15/10/27 02:37:37 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 46 from textFile at null:
-1
```

Also, do we always use backslashes in the command line when using Windows? Or is it just for directories?

Comment: Can you just try "sample.txt"?

Comment: OK, so what is the error? What you've shown so far is a normal log.

Comment: just sample.txt won't work. The error is, that I get the same log for every argument of textField()

Comment: even if I try the "input = sc.textField("README.md")" from the apache spark tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Can you give [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) a try

```
import os
input = sc.textFile(os.path.normpath("D:/sample.txt"))
```

> **os.path.normpath(path)**
>
> Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level
>   references so that A//B, A/B/, A/./B and A/foo/../B all become A/B.
>   This string manipulation may change the meaning of a path that
>   contains symbolic links. On Windows, it converts forward slashes to
>   backward slashes. To normalize case, use normcase().

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work :( Since nothing works it seems more like a configuration issue. Ideas would be much appreciated.